# Edittext editable and un editable in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

**Code**

```
 edtAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtAddress);
 edtAddress.setTag(edtAddress.getKeyListener());
 edtAddress.setKeyListener(null);
 imgEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            edtAddress.setKeyListener((KeyListener) edtAddress.getTag());
        }
    });
```

HI, i have a problem while open app then the edit text is not editable, but when click on edit button then that edit text is editable.

i have done this code but, problem is that when i click on edit button then edit text(edtAddress) is editable but, when type any character then edit text is not getting input character and app is crash.

what is the problem there, suggest me

**ERROR**

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.hit.fyl_owner, PID: 3128
                                                             java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
                                                                 at android.graphics.Canvas.drawText(Canvas.java:1696)
                                                                 at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:410)
                                                                 at android.widget.Editor.drawHardwareAccelerated(Editor.java:1585)
                                                                 at android.widget.Editor.onDraw(Editor.java:1507)
                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:5715)
                                                                 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16178)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15134)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15134)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15134)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15134)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15134)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15134)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3593)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3573)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15134)
                                                                 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:281)
                                                                 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:287)
                                                                 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:322)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2615)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2434)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: why `edtAddress.setKeyListener(null);` ?

Comment: edtAddress.setFocusable(false) to stop editing .setFocusableInTouchMode(true) to re-enable it.

Comment: @BradleyWilson yes

Comment: @RameshKumar post your error code.log cat

Comment: you are getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: my edittext is maxline and minline is 3. if single line then its work fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133439/discussion-between-ramesh-kumar-and-intellij-amiya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set edittext disable.

```
edtOrganization.setFocusable(false);
```

now you can set edittext enable.

```
edtFirst.setFocusable(true);
edtFirst.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this code,

```
edtAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtAddress);
edtAddress.setEnabled(false);
imgEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        edtAddress.setEnabled(true);
        edtAddress.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

Comment: my edittext is maxline and minline is 3. if single line then its work fine

Comment: how does it related with enabling or disabling ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add "requestFocus", which focuses the EditText

```
     <EditText...>
        <requestFocus />
     </EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your EditText xml file:

```
<EditText ...
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:cursorVisible="false" 
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added two attributes

`android:singleLine="true"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

and everything started working as normal. Well, I still do not understand the cause and may dig into it further but hope this will help for now.